# Property 'setServerTrustMode' does not exist on type 'HTTP'. (Plugin-Advanced-HTTP )

Tags: http, ionic3

I'm trying to use 'setServerTrustMode' in this pugin cordova-plugin-advanced-http, but I get error `Property 'setServerTrustMode' does not exist on type 'HTTP'.`

I'm using "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^2.4.0" and "@ionic-native/http": "^4.20.0",

I already try remove 'http' from constructor but still not working.

Here is my code

```html
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';

constructor(private http: HTTP)
{}

public test(){

        this.http.setServerTrustMode('nocheck', function () {
           console.log('success!');
       }, function () {
           console.log('error :(');
       });
}
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Look at [this](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/3167).

Seems that ionic-native does not have the last version of the plugin.

I'm trying to install the plugin without the ionic native wrapper.